# Make an app show up as an Android lock screen?

Tags: android

I haven't found a definite answer to this yet. Lots of apps let you build/install custom lock screens without root, etc. It's just like installing an app. I found this in the dev guide: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED

I assume that while this is running it would run just like any other app. But how would I "release" it to let the user get to their home screen? And do I need to handle things like incoming phone calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (at least if you follow the rules) replace the secure lock screen.  You can have a lock-screen like activity that will show up when the phone is locked.  Use FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED, but notice that your activity cannot be transparent - i.e. it cannot be a dialog.