# Android:Make my app as the default Home screen locker

Tags: android

I have created new authentication method and now need to  replace the current home screen lock(maze lock) with my app...i have created and tested the app as a standalone program but now i need to make  it the home screen locker..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it's possible. At least pre-ICS, Google do not allow the Android lock/authentication screen to be replaced - most likely for security reasons. There are various ways of doing it on a rooted or custom ROM of course and others have found a way of "top-screening" (i.e. making your Window appear above the lock screen, but not actually replace it), but if you're looking for a ReplaceLockScreen() API, it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to be much out there on this, but seems that it has been asked here

[Make an app show up as an Android lock screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465232/make-an-app-show-up-as-an-android-lock-screen)

Looking at the source of android might help.

[Source of Android's lock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140964/android-lock-screen-source-code)