# Android 4.4+ how to make a app become Screen Lock

Tags: android

I got a problem about how to create a simple Screen Lock for my Android devices (4.4.2)
I tried some ways, including disabling back, home and recent keys, but as far as I know, since android 4, I can't disable home and recent keys anymore due to security, so only back key is disabled.
I don't know what to do to handle this.
Any suggestions?
Please let me know.
Thank you in advanced

Comment: maybe this link will help http://stackoverflow.com/a/16758126

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make an app show up as an Android lock screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465232/make-an-app-show-up-as-an-android-lock-screen)

Comment: @Mochamad Taufik Hidayat 
I don't think that's a good way to do this.
because it essentialy launches the activity again when it is closed. And if I press Home button, it takes me 6 minutes to launch the top view again.
Why there is no tutorial about how to create something like stock screen lock?

Comment: @All :- can i get current foreground app?